# MATLAB: How to solve high dimensional nonlinear ODE?

Tags: matlab, simulation, mathematical-optimization, ode, nonlinear-functions

I have an ODE:

> x' = -x + f(x)

Looks simple enough, but x is 100 dimensional i.e.

> x = [x1, ... , x100]

Furthermore,

> fi(x) = ln(xi)/(ln(x1)+...+ln(x100))

where i is between 1 and 100 and f(x) = [f1(x), ... , f100(x)]

On MATLAB's website, it says I should first create a function as:

[image]

But how can I do this? I have 100 variables, and all my variables are coupled through that highly nonlinear function.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function can leverage the vectorization capabilities of MATLAB since, from the [`ode45` documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html#inputarg_odefun), the "function `dydt = odefun(t,y)`, for a scalar `t` and a column vector `y`, must return a column vector `dydt`".  So your `odefun` can be expressed simply as

```
function dxdt = odefun(~,x)
    logX = log(x);
    dxdt = -x + logX/sum(logX);
end
```

and let `ode45`, or another appropriate integrator, handle the rest.